# collision detection locked to the top left of a picture box?

Tags: vb.net

I have managed to get the player picture box to collide with a collectable picture box. This makes the collectable disappear. However, the collision is not detected unless the top left of the player picture box is colliding with the collectable.

Is there a way to detect a collision with the whole picture box, rather than just the top left?

This is the code I'm using.

```
If Player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Collectable.Bounds) Then
        Diamond1.Hide()
        PlayerScore = PlayerScore + CollectableValue
End If
```

Comment: As long as the Width and Height (or Right/Bottom I forget) are set for both bounds, it shouldn't behave like you state. It should trigger as soon as any parts overlap

Comment: Your code is flawless, I think the problem is somewhere else.